# What is the use of grep TLS command in linux?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am working in a shell script and came across one command which is below:

```
echo $line | grep TLS > /dev/null
```

What is the meaning of this?

Comment: Your favourite search engine would probably have given you the answer much faster. It simply looks for the string `TLS` within the output of `echo $line`.

Comment: @Biffen - of course that is technically correct, but then why just throw away the result - perhaps that is the real question here, and to be fair google didn't answer that.

Comment: @GemTaylor True, but the title only asks about `grep TLS`. And to know more we’d need to see more. Sloppy question; sloppy reply.

Comment: Difficult to tell, perhaps you can show the script it is in.
The programmer was sloppy, he should know he should quote the `"${line}"`. Perhaps he was trying to test the content (looking at `$?` or with `set -e`) unaware of better methods. Or is was a debug statement he didn't want to remove (or put `#` in front of it).

Answer (score 0):

Echo `$line` variable.

If the variable's content has lines, containing `TLS` character sequence, then output those line into `/dev/null` (effectively: "get rid of them").

I don't see any useful application of this line by itself. It doesn't produce any useful output. Unless you are interested in the exit code of the pipeline may be.